# Use calculated field in AWS QuickSight analysis to compute fraction with different aggregation level in denominator than in numerator

Tags: bar-chart, amazon-quicksight, calculated-field

I have a dataset which contains entries for outlets. Each entry has a field `outlet ID`, `outlet name`, `state`, and `product name` (simplified). Each outlet can have 1 (if it offers none of the products) or several entries, one additional entry for each product (with a different `product name`) offered.

I want to create a bar chart which shows for each filtered product a fraction - the product coverage for each product, i.e., the number of outlets which offer a certain product (numerator) divided by total outlets (denominator). This data could also later be grouped, e.g., by states, or other filters could be applied to the outlets, e.g., only outlets are taken into consideration which offer at least one product out of a set of certain products.

How can I achieve this?

As I understand it, it is not possible to create a calculated field which computes a fraction where the aggregation level in the denominator is different from the numerator. That means, when in the field well the `X axis` contains the field `product name` and the value contains the calculated field, that calculated field to be calculated as `distinct_count({outlet ID}) / distinctCountOver({outlet ID}, [], PRE_AGG)` is not possible.

I tried this:

In the field well for the bar chart the `X axis` contains the field `product name` and the value contains the calculated field which is defined to be calculated as `distinct_count({outlet ID}) / distinctCountOver({outlet ID}, [], PRE_AGG)`.

I got this error message: “Mismatched aggregation. Custom aggregations can’t contain both aggregate “distinctCountOver” and non-aggregated fields “DISTINCTCOUNTOVER(“outlet ID”, PRE_AGG)”, in any combination.”

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution and the explanation for a similar case here:

https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/big-data/create-advanced-insights-using-level-aware-aggregations-in-amazon-quicksight/

As I understand it, because of the different aggregation levels in the numerator and the denominator (where I use LAC-W to change the aggregation level), you have in the numerator a set of numbers, the total of outlets for each product. However, because the denominator is not aggregated, the set of numbers in the denominator has more items because each record contains a total. When you add `min()` to the denominator to reduce the number of totals to the number of products, `distinct_count({object ID}) / min(distinctCountOver({object ID}, [], PRE_FILTER))` doesn’t throw an error.

This is the explanation given in the reference:

> Compute the fixed percent of total sales.
>
> Calculated field name : fixedPercentOfTotal
>
> Calculated field expression : sum(sales) /
> min(totalSalesBeforeFilters)
>
> Note: totalSalesBeforeFilters is the same for every row of the
> unaggregated data. Since we want to use it post-aggregation, we are
> using the aggregation min on top of it. If all values are the same,
> max or avg aggregations can be used as well as it serves the same
> purpose.